# ionic 3 reorder columns by dragging

Tags: angular, typescript, grid, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 angular to build a website. The one page is more of a portal where there are different size widgets.  I have built is using a general idea of

```
<ion-grid>
 <ion-row>
   <ion-col col-auto>
   ...
   </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-auto>
   ...
   </ion-col>
   ...
  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

So basically a single row in a grid with all col-auto. This simply flows the column down if they cant come in a single row depending.  Which is what I want.

However, one thing I really need is to be able to drag a column and move it to another position which will basically change the layout for me on the fly.

how do i do that?